# TypeError: einsatznummer_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have tried to add a kind of custom id to my Django model, which is built according to the date of a model field. This should be built according to the format: [year][number]. (e.g. 2021001, 2021002, 2021003..., 2022001)

For this purpose, I have designed the following model, which returns the error:

> TypeError: insert_number_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

Because of einsatznummer_generator() is not a class, I don't have to initialise it. Can someone please explain the error in my Custom ID?

###### my models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.fields import CharField, NullBooleanField
import datetime

class EinsatzPublic(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,"Entwurf"),
        (1,"Öffentlich"),
        (2,"Archiv"),
        (3,"Papierkorb"),
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, verbose_name="Autor")
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False, verbose_name="Erstellt")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True, editable=False, verbose_name="Aktualisiert")
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0, verbose_name="Status")

    einsatz_start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Einsatzbeginn")
    einsatz_end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Einsatzende")

#! Custom ID:

    def einsatznummer_generator(self):
        year_einsatz = self.einsatz_start.strftime('%Y')

        last_number = EinsatzPublic.objects.filter(einsatznummer__isnull=False).latest('einsatznummer')
        if last_number == None:
            last_number = 000
        elif last_number[:-3] != year_einsatz:
            last_number = 000
        einsatznummer_gen = year_einsatz + (last_number + 1)
        
        return einsatznummer_gen

    einsatznummer = models.IntegerField(default=einsatznummer_generator() ,verbose_name="Einsatznummer", editable=False)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
        verbose_name = "Einsatz"
        verbose_name_plural = "Einsätze"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit because I did not understand your question correctly:
You can't generate a default value based on other fields of the object because if the object doesn't exist yet, those fields don't exist too.

What you can do is define a model property with the @property decorator:

```
    class EinsatzPublic(models.Model):
        STATUS = (
            (0,"Entwurf"),
            (1,"Öffentlich"),
            (2,"Archiv"),
            (3,"Papierkorb"),
        )
        author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, verbose_name="Autor")
        created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False, verbose_name="Erstellt")
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True, editable=False, verbose_name="Aktualisiert")
        status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0, verbose_name="Status")
    
        einsatz_start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Einsatzbeginn")
        einsatz_end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Einsatzende")
    
        @property
        def einsatznummer(self):
            year_einsatz = self.einsatz_start.strftime('%Y')
    
            last_number = EinsatzPublic.objects.filter(einsatznummer__isnull=False, einsatz_start__year=year_einsatz).latest('id').einsatznummer
            if last_number == None:
                last_number = 000
            elif last_number[:-3] != year_einsatz:
                last_number = 000
            einsatznummer_gen = year_einsatz + (last_number + 1)
            
            return einsatznummer_gen
    
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created']
            verbose_name = "Einsatz"
            verbose_name_plural = "Einsätze"
```

Then you can access the einsatznummer property like any other field.

Comment: This leads to the same error for me.  `TypeError: einsatznummer_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'`

Comment: I defined the generator before the model and called it without parantheses.

Answer (score 0):

It's method, so you need to call it via `self.`

```
default=self.einsatznummer_generator
```

And do not call the function, pass it without parantheses.

Comment: This leads me to the error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Because you moved your method our of class. In your first implementation `einsatznummer_generator` was method inside class and that's why you needed to do with `self.`